# Smoothness of the total space of a family of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\Delta=\textrm{Spec}\,\mathbb C[[t]]$ be the formal disk and $f:Y\to \Delta$ a flat projective family of (complex stable) curves, such that the generic curve $Y_s$ of the family is smooth and the special fiber $Y_0$ is a reducible nodal curve with singularity set $N\subset Y_0$. (Here $s$ denotes the generic point of $\Delta$ and $0$ its closed point.)

Is it true that the total space of the family, namely the surface $Y$, is smooth away from $N$? (In other words: the singular points of $Y$, if any, are in $N$).

Thanks for any hint or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $Y' = Y \setminus N$, then the morphism $Y' \to \Delta$ has reduced, smooth, fibres, and so a general theorem implies that it is a smooth morphism.  (See e.g. the definition at the beginning of the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_morphism).)   Since $\Delta$ is (formally) smooth, it follows that $Y'$ is (formally) smooth.  (If we were actually over a non-trivial disk, so that *the total space* of $Y'$ makes sense as an actual
complex analytic space, then $Y'$ would be a smooth complex analytic space.)

Comment: It took some time to understand your "(formally)" but now I got it. Thanks! Do you know if a more elementary argument (involving e.g. dimension of tangent spaces) is possible?

Comment: @Brenin: Dear Brenin, I didn't think much about it, but have you tried looking at the discussion of smooth morphisms in Hartshorne, maybe Prop. III.10.4 and its proof?  That discussion is mainly about comparing fibres, maps on tangent spaces, and related stuff, so might contain an implicit, or even explicit, answer to your question.  Regards,

Comment: I know this answer is old right now, still I hope that anyone is willing to answer. You are saying that $Y'$ is smooth because $\Delta$ is. How does that follows? I looked at the Proposition in Hartshorne that you suggested, but it didn't help me.