# Smooth morphism has smooth source

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am asking this question in order to understand the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/543432/526015) five years old question. I also added a comment there, but the user answering the question hasn't been active for years so I don't expect to get an answer there.

In the question mentioned above, it is claimed that a smooth morphism $X\to Y$ has smooth source, i.e. that $X$ is smooth. I was unable to find this statement anywhere and I have no idea at all about how to see this is true.

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y$ is smooth and $f:X \to Y$ is smooth then $X$ is smooth (this is Hartshorne III.10.1(c) for $Z$ a point). If $Y$ is singular then $X$ is singular as well (the simplest example is when $f$ is an isomorphism).

Comment: I tried to find it in Hartshorne but didn't manage. Can you give me the precise theorem in Hartshorne? Whenever I read something about smoothness of $X$ or $Y$, it is an assumption to make a statement.

Comment: @James: This is III.10.1(c) for $Z$ a point.

Comment: So the argument is that $X$ is smooth if and only if $X\to\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C)$ is a smooth morphism together with the fact that the composition of smooth morphisms is smooth?

Comment: @James: Correct.

Comment: OK, got it. Thank you for your help :)